# Incorrect plugin instalation with Magento Connect Manager on v1.9.2.4

Tags: magento-connect, ce-1.9.2.4, magento-connect-manager

I am testing my plugin on Magento version 1.9.2.4. Installation on Magento Connect Manager seems to be ok but when I try to find it in configuration tab in Admin Panel - it's not there (it works on earlier versions for example 1.9), so I went to directories where it should be installed and I found something strange... Magento changed every php file from my plugin package to empty directories, for example:

> app/code/community/SalesManago/Tracking/Block/Layer.php

It's now a folder with "Layer.php" name and it's empty.

I need to copy everything manually to install it correctly... Does anyone had this problem before?

Comment: This is not a problem of Magento. This is problem of operating system which is not understanding type of element which is being copied.

Comment: I am testing it on localhost (Ubuntu 14.04), on v1.9 everything its ok but on 1.9.2.4 it fails - the same host.

Comment: Edit: Now on the v1.9 I have the same problem. Do you know how can I fix it ?

Comment: It may be due to incorrect folder permissions or some infection by malware. But I can't say exactly.
If you find it's solution, please let me know also.

Comment: Ok, thx for replay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem. It was extension package format, when I try to install my plugin with *.tar.gz format it fails like I describe above, but when I change it to *.tgz it work correctly! Maybe someone has the same problem, so this is an answer.